# create a sample matrix from the main matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I want to create a sample matrix from the main one with the sam number of columns but less rows (50) I tried to use a series of loops but it didn't work:

```
n=nrow(data)
camp <- sample(1:n,size=50,replace=TRUE)


n<-length(camp)
c<-ncol(data)
for(i in 1:n){
      t<-camp[i]
    for(k in 1:c){
    campione[i,k]<-data[t,k]}
}
```

Comment: you want `data[camp,]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use loop. You just have to take random lines from your main matrix:

```
mat = matrix(runif(2000),ncol=20)

sample_matrix = mat[sample(1:nrow(mat),50),]
```